# Chef server routine crash

Tags: chef-infra

We have a standalone Chef server installation (v 12.1.2). It has been running fine for months but recently it has started crashing few times a day. Looking at the logs, it seem like the "opscode-erchef" service crashes few times a day. This is from the opscode-erchef crash log:

```
    2017-07-28 08:44:26 =ERROR REPORT====
["Could not connect, scheduling reconnect.",{error,{{error,{badmatch,{error,{auth_failure_likely,{econnrefused,{gen_server,call,[<0.2016.0>,connect,infinity]}}}}},[{bunny_util,connect,1,[{file,"src/bunny_util.erl"},{line,191}]},{gen_bunny_mon,do_connect,3,[{file,"src/gen_bunny_mon.erl"},{line,192}]},{gen_bunny_mon,handle_info,2,[{file,"src/gen_bunny_mon.erl"},{line,134}]},{gen_server,try_dispatch,4,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,593}]},{gen_server,handle_msg,5,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,659}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,237}]}]},{connection_info,{network,{127,0,0,1},5672,{<<"chef">>,<<"de073b36fa2831124fc06a121702610c1ddaf367cc9aad74e9a9ba7381fa355a9fd8aaf4be57745fecfc0f0a1c275aab3190">>},<<"/analytics">>}}}}]
2017-07-28 08:44:26 =ERROR REPORT====
Could not start the network driver: econnrefused
2017-07-28 08:44:26 =ERROR REPORT====
** Generic server <0.2019.0> terminating
** Last message in was connect
** When Server state == {state,<0.2017.0>,{amqp_params,<<"chef">>,<<"de073b36fa2831124fc06a121702610c1ddaf367cc9aad74e9a9ba7381fa355a9fd8aaf4be57745fecfc0f0a1c275aab3190">>,<<"/chef">>,{127,0,0,1},5672,0,0,0,none,[]},undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,<0.2018.0>,false,undefined,{{0,nil},{dict,0,16,16,8,80,48,{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]},{{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]}}}},undefined,#Fun<amqp_connection_sup.0.94524864>}
** Reason for termination ==
** {econnrefused,[{amqp_network_connection,do_connect,1,[{file,"src/amqp_network_connection.erl"},{line,337}]},{amqp_network_connection,handle_call,3,[{file,"src/amqp_network_connection.erl"},{line,93}]},{gen_server,try_handle_call,4,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,607}]},{gen_server,handle_msg,5,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,639}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,237}]}]}
2017-07-28 08:44:26 =CRASH REPORT====
  crasher:
    initial call: amqp_network_connection:init/1
    pid: <0.2019.0>
    registered_name: []
    exception exit: {econnrefused,[{gen_server,terminate,7,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,804}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,237}]}]}
    ancestors: [<0.2017.0>,gen_bunny_mon,gen_bunny_sup,<0.1531.0>]
    messages: []
    links: [<0.2017.0>]
    dictionary: []
    trap_exit: false
    status: running
    heap_size: 610
    stack_size: 27
    reductions: 531
  neighbours:
2017-07-28 08:44:26 =SUPERVISOR REPORT====
     Supervisor: {<0.2017.0>,amqp_connection_sup}
     Context:    child_terminated
     Reason:     econnrefused
     Offender:   [{pid,<0.2019.0>},{name,connection},{mfa,{amqp_network_connection,start_link,[{amqp_params,<<"chef">>,<<"de073b36fa2831124fc06a121702610c1ddaf367cc9aad74e9a9ba7381fa355a9fd8aaf4be57745fecfc0f0a1c275aab3190">>,<<"/chef">>,{127,0,0,1},5672,0,0,0,none,[]},<0.2018.0>,#Fun<amqp_connection_sup.0.94524864>]}},{restart_type,intrinsic},{shutdown,brutal_kill},{child_type,worker}]

2017-07-28 08:44:26 =SUPERVISOR REPORT====
     Supervisor: {<0.2017.0>,amqp_connection_sup}
     Context:    shutdown
     Reason:     reached_max_restart_intensity
     Offender:   [{pid,<0.2019.0>},{name,connection},{mfa,{amqp_network_connection,start_link,[{amqp_params,<<"chef">>,<<"de073b36fa2831124fc06a121702610c1ddaf367cc9aad74e9a9ba7381fa355a9fd8aaf4be57745fecfc0f0a1c275aab3190">>,<<"/chef">>,{127,0,0,1},5672,0,0,0,none,[]},<0.2018.0>,#Fun<amqp_connection_sup.0.94524864>]}},{restart_type,intrinsic},{shutdown,brutal_kill},{child_type,worker}]

Rettarting opscode-erchef followed by opscode-expander service brings it back again.
```

Can anyone tell, in what case opscode-erchef service would crash ? I don't see any strain on CPU or memory when it happens. So server resource doesn't seem to be an issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors have to do with RabbitMQ and the workers; try increasing the amount of connections available to RabbitMQ or adjusting the timeouts or increasing the connections.

`rabbitmq['rabbit_mgmt_http_max_count']`

> The maximum worker count for the HTTP connection pool that is used by the rabbitmq-management plugin. Default value: 100.

`rabbitmq['rabbit_mgmt_timeout']`

> The timeout for the HTTP connection pool that is used by the rabbitmq-management plugin. Default value: 30000.

To see how to change the settings and other settings that are adjustable, take a look [here](https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_server_optional_settings.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try bumping up the rabbitmq parameters. Will let you know if it helps.

Comment: I increased the rabbitmq['rabbit_mgmt_http_max_count'] parameter to 200 and did a chef-server-ctl reconfigure but it did not help. Now,  my chef server is not starting up and I see following error in opscode-erchef current log: 2017-07-31_19:11:14.73681 =ERROR REPORT==== 31-Jul-2017::14:11:14 ===
2017-07-31_19:11:14.73682 pool 'sqerl': exceeded timeout waiting for 20 members
2017-07-31_19:11:14.78063 =ERROR REPORT==== 31-Jul-2017::14:11:14 ===
2017-07-31_19:11:14.78064 ** Generic server <0.1020.0> terminating

Comment: The sqerl pooler_timeout parameter was set to 0. Increased it to 1000 and it resolved the timeout error. The server is back up and running.

Comment: I agree, it may have just delayed the inevitable. But it hasn't gone down in last 24 hour. We will be monitoring it and see how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: I think two issues happened here -1) The original issue which seemed to be related with Rabbitmq (econnrefused,[{amqp_network_connection). I am yet to verify your answer with that issue. 2) Second issue happened after I tried to update the rabbitmq parameter and did a reconfigure. The server just went down and would not come up until I increased the sqerl pooler_timeout.   I would accept your answer for the second issue to increase the sqerl timeout parameter :)